# Arch Unable to get correct battery information

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, arch-linux, battery

Edit: Everything works on Ubuntu, but on Arch, it does not update, either via restarting the daemon, acpi -V or using inxi.
Also the AC Power adapter doesn't do anything (at least in arch) so no status update etc.

---

Hello I Installed Arch on my new laptop, however, the battery percentage/percentage update seems to be broken, I have never seen this before and could really find anything useful which might help.

I installed `ACPI` and tried to downgrade `upower`, also disabled `session restore` in KDE settings as well as fast boot inside `UEFI`.

I booted from USB into ubuntu and the battery works there, I used `lspci -nnk` to view the modules/components and what drivers they use, there are only two things that don't match arch's `lspci -nnk` output.

The driver (and kernel module used) for the Signal Processing Controller is `intel-pmt` on Ubuntu and `intel_vsec` on arch.
The driver for the Serial Bus Controller doesn't seem to have any modules or drivers present under Ubuntu, but on Arch it uses `intel-spi` as the driver and `spi_intel_pci` as the kernel module.

> The Laptop in question is a Fujitsu Lifebook A3511 (i3-11th gen)
>
> > Ubuntu Upower version: 0.99.17 | Original Arch Upower version: 0.99.20
> >
> > > Downgraded Arch's version to 0.99.19, .18, .17 and .10 (nothing worked).

> **Extra Info**
>
> > Vanilla Arch (5.19.6-arch1-1), Encrypted NVME drive (Luks), Grub bootloader, pretty much everything else works, just that stupid battery not updating smh.

---

## Full `lspci -nnk` output (Ubuntu)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a04] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a78] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:004f]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [8086:9a03] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module [8086:9a11] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited GNA Scoring Accelerator module [1e26:0057]
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver [8086:9a0d] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-pmt
    Kernel modules: intel_pmt
00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller [8086:9a13] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a0ed] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM [8086:a0ef] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM [1e26:0057]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface [8086:a0e0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0d3] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b8] (rev 20)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0bc] (rev 20)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b1] (rev 20)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller [8086:a082] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller [1e26:0057]
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [1e26:0040]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller [8086:a0a3] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller [1e26:0057]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller [8086:a0a4] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller [1e26:0057]
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1e26:0017]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [1e26:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

---

## Full `lspci -nnk` output (Arch)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a04] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a78] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:004f]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [8086:9a03] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
        Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module [8086:9a11] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver [8086:9a0d] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: intel_vsec
        Kernel modules: intel_vsec
00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller [8086:9a13] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a0ed] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM [8086:a0ef] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface [8086:a0e0] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SATA Controller [8086:a0d3] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b8] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0bc] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b1] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller [8086:a082] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0040]
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller [8086:a0a3] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller [8086:a0a4] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0057]
        Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
        Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0017]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Device [1e26:0019]
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after posting the same issue in Arch's Discord community, a member suggested using the LTS kernel.

This has fixed the issue completely, correct battery percentage with live update, and status.

---

### To change your kernel (on arch)

1. Get the linux-lts package via pacman or other means (I use yay)

```sh
yay -S linux-lts
```

2. Run mkinitcpio

```sh
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux-lts
```

3. Remove the standard linux kernel (Optional)

> I suggest keeping it for testing/fallback if lts doesn't help.

```sh
yay -R linux
```

4. Update grub

```sh
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

5. Reboot

> If you didn't remove the standard kernel select advanced options for Arch and select to boot with the lts kernel
> 6. Verify the kernel (output should have something ending in `-lts`)

```sh
uname -r
```